# Flicker of unstyled content in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, browser, internet-explorer-8

I built this site a couple of years back and but am now in the process of moving it to a new server.

However. I've noticed there is a split second of unstyled content show on page load when viewed in Firefox (3.5.7)?

And on checking in IE8, a less frequent and slightly more raggged effect also happens but only prior to caching?

The url is: http://www.rhubarbrentals.co.uk

If anyone can suggest how to fix this I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery for this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#flash').hide();
});
```

where #flash is the div that contains your unstyled content. check this [link](http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/10/1-way-to-avoid-the-flash-of-unstyled-content) for more details

Answer (score 0):

putting the

```
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

at the bottom of the page (right above `</body>`) might help some.